# iPhone Application Design Question

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have done some iPhone application development but still am relatively new at it. My question is, how do I design an interface like the face interface, where you have icons that you click that take you to certain things? Is there a template for this in xcode?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to refine your question to be a little more specific...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no templates or UIKit classes that constructs a matrix of views. You will have to implement them yourself, or read about Three20 library (specifically launcher module) if it's relevant to what you want to implement.

link : http://three20.info/showcase/launcher